# How to determine if process has root privileges in a network kernel extension?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm writing a socket filter kext and I would want to ignore any connections made as root. Before OS X Lion, the following code worked flawlessly:

```
static boolean_t is_root() {
    proc_t p = proc_self();
    boolean_t isRoot = proc_suser(p);
    proc_rele(p);
    return isRoot;
}
```

But now with Lion and Mountain Lion, the `is_root()` function always returns true. In Snow Leopard, it worked as I imagined it would.

Here's an example of how I tested the function inside a socket filter event handler:

```
int debugPid = proc_selfpid();
if (is_root()) {
    printf("%u (root)\n", debugPid);
} else {
    printf("%u (user)\n", debugPid);
}
```

But the output always says "root", for example:

```
2012-11-15 3:48:00.000 PM kernel[0]: 29879 (root)
```

Where the app making the connection is Twitter (confirmed through the PID). Twitter runs with regular user privileges, not root.

Is there a better/correct way to determine if the process behind the socket connection has root privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the `bsd/sys/proc.h` ([link](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/bsd/sys/proc.h)):

```
/* this routine returns error if the process is not one with super user privileges */
int proc_suser(proc_t p);
```

So a return of `0` means the process has root privileges or non-zero otherwise.

You want:

```
static boolean_t is_root() {
    proc_t p = proc_self();
    int error = proc_suser(p);
    proc_rele(p);
    return error == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't know how I misread that. Also I could have sworn that the code worked back when I had Snow Leopard installed.

Comment: The `proc_xxx()` funcs are inconsistent, for example `proc_exiting()` returns boolean (1/0).